# Conditional clause in COUNT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem in my request:

```
SELECT regionn, COUNT(regionn) AS total,
COUNT(last_date_o) AS ouvreurs,
COUNT(last_date_o)*100/COUNT(regionn) AS ratio,
COUNT(gender='mr'), COUNT(gender='mme')
FROM data WHERE length(regionn)=2
GROUP BY regionn ORDER BY regionn ASC
```

the gender column has 2 possible values: 'mr' or 'mme'.
With COUNT(gender='mr'), COUNT(gender='mme') I want the total of each, but the same value is return.

In fact COUNT(gender='mr'), COUNT(gender='mme') is exactly the same as COUNT(gender), COUNT(gender)...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT` is not the right aggregator for this, you should use `SUM`.

> In fact `COUNT(gender='mr')`, `COUNT(gender='mme')` is exactly the same as `COUNT(gender)`

This is because `COUNT` counts anything that's not `NULL`, while `SUM` will add up ones and zeros.

```
SELECT
    regionn
,   COUNT(regionn) AS total
,   COUNT(last_date_o) AS ouvreurs\
,   COUNT(last_date_o)*100/COUNT(regionn) AS ratio
,   SUM(CASE WHEN gender='mr' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mrs
,   SUM(CASE WHEN gender='mme' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mmes
FROM data
WHERE length(regionn)=2
GROUP BY regionn
ORDER BY regionn ASC
```

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight, but I got "HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts." at >SUM(gender... any idea ?

Comment: @Macbernie Try the updated version. I don't have a Postgresql instance handy to try this out, but the updated expression should work on most RDBMS engines.

Comment: Your last update do the job, even in my postgresql 9.1 ! Thanks @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @Macbernie It should, because `CASE` is very portable, while `COUNT(condition OR null)` is a non-portable syntax specific to Postgresql.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight This syntax has nothing special in it. Just SQL standart tri-state boolean logic.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko Well, a standard syntax that does not work on Oracle or MS SQL Server, two engines that cover more than 50% of RDBMS market share, remains non-portable, no matter how standard it may be. Postgresql is historically at the forefront of adopting various SQL features, such using expressions like this in aggregating functions, but mainstream engines are not so eager to catch up. Another example is regex searches: Postgresql has fantastic support of regex, while other engines are nowhere near it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT regionn, 
COUNT(regionn) AS total,
COUNT(last_date_o) AS ouvreurs,
COUNT(last_date_o)*100/COUNT(regionn) AS ratio,
COUNT(gender='mr' or null), 
COUNT(gender='mme' or null)
FROM data WHERE length(regionn)=2
GROUP BY regionn ORDER BY regionn ASC
```

Explanation for `COUNT(gender='mr' or null)`:

For `gender` == `mr`

`count(gender='mr' or null)` => `count('mr'='mr' or null)` => `count(true or null)` => `count(true)` => `1`

For `gender` == `mme`

`count(gender='mr' or null)` => `count('mme'='mr' or null)` => `count(false or null)` => `count(null)` => `0`

This trick uses the fact that `true or null == true` and `false or null == null`

Comment: It do the job ! What is this madness ?!